# Do different merchants pay more for items depending on their type?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For example I found a staff with a value of 2000+. Would it be worth it look for a merchant that sells magic-related stuff as opposed to dumping it on the next general store guy I find?

Comment: +1 Good question. I've been wondering the same thing. Also, welcome to the site.

Comment: +1 I am curious about this as well. Great question!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tested:

I sold a gold necklace to the general goods merchant in Whiterun for 47 gold.  I then traveled to Riften and sold a gold necklace to the jeweler there.  Again 47 gold.

It seems that an **items type bears no significance** as long as the merchant is willing to buy it.  Other factors such as the Allure perk **can** change an items value depending on the merchant

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, Speechcraft determines amount of money for transactions.

*However*. I'm sure there's a hidden mechanic for how well someone likes you which determines money yeild on items. Also certain people will buy only certain items. Example: a spellcaster type will buy your spell tomes while the guy from Warmaiden won't.

Comment: Unless you get the speech perk that allows you to sell everything to everyone.

Comment: Or just go to the Thieves Guild and sell there.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, there's that cheap lizard guy in Riften who pays a lot less for your items. If you are in the Thieves Guild, sell your items to that chick — she has better prices for all good/stolen goods.